# Versions of JDK with able Java Collections Framework

Tags: java, collections, frameworks, version

Since what version Java Collections Framework are added in the JDK?

Comment: Always read the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Collections Framework introduced in JDK version 1.2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework

Answer (score 1):

Java collections introduced in JDK 1.2